# Events surrounding Japanese coronation

Tags: japan, event-based-effects

October 22nd is the coronation date for the new Japanese emperor who acceded in May 2019. What kind of public events can be expected on this day? Specifically I'd like to know if public celebrations are planned in and outside of Tokyo.

This is a pretty rare occasion and could be interesting to witness, but I don't really know what to expect: is this a private ceremony? are there big celebrations planned? if so, are they mostly confined to Tokyo? will there be important security/mobility disruptions in the capital?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There will be essentially no impact.** The coronation will take place on the grounds of the Imperial Palace, very much off limits to the public, and subsequent celebrations consist of a banquet limited to a few hundred invited guests only.

In general, the Japanese Imperial family both holds itself at arm's length from and is kept at a distance by the general public, and there's no tradition of royal pomp and public hysteria to the extent you'd see in (say) the UK or Thailand.

More reading: https://www.nippon.com/en/japan-topics/c06107/japan-to-spend-record-%C2%A516-6-billion-on-coronation-of-new-emperor.html